# Wordpress categories being called "archives" in google links. How to remove?

Tags: categories, archives, google

We have several category pages. When you find these links on google we noticed that google is adding the name "Archive" to all our category pages.

How do i change this? I would like to remove the reference all together.

Thanks for any help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90daz.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely that you are using an SEO tool.  Go to the settings for that tool and remove the word "archive" from the archive section of your SEO.  If you DON'T have SEO tool, then get one.  An example would be Yoast (this is by no means a recommendation, just an example) and in it's settings you'll be able to remove the "archive" from archive titles.